# Getting all SQL Server VARCHAR types in C#

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, ascii

Can someone help me figure out why I'm getting

> Fatal Error: Memory usage limit was exceeded

with the following

```
private static IEnumerable<char> AllSqlVarChars ()
{
    List<char> chars = new List<char>(256);
    for(byte b = 0; b <= 255; ++b)
        chars.Add((char)b);
    return chars;       
}
```

or help me come up with a better way of getting a collection of all C# `char`s that correspond to SQL Server `VARCHAR`s.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ?

Comment: Are you looking for the list of all characters supported by the default collation of a database? There is, I'm afraid, no simple way of getting that. In particular, simply enumerating from 0 to 255 will not do it because collations can be multi-byte: this naive approach will fail for Japanese, Chinese, Thai, etc. What's your *real* problem? If you want to ensure your collation supports all characters you want to store, you can check that against the collation (they all represent certain encodings that are documented). Better yet, if there's any doubt, use `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Actually, you're going from the first 256 C# chars (code points U+0000 through U+00FF) and then presumably looking if these fit in a `VARCHAR` somehow. That's actually even *less* helpful in general and just makes me wonder even more what your actual underlying question is. Yes, the code fix is trivial, but what about the results?

Comment: If (and only if) your collation is single byte, you can query for all characters in it using `SELECT TOP(256) CONVERT(CHAR(1), CONVERT(BINARY(1), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name) - 1))
FROM master.dbo.spt_values`. Note that the values will *not* correspond 1-to-1 with the same values as C# chars. For example, U+0080 is a control code, but 0x80 in the Latin1_General collation is the euro sign. The euro sign is U+20AC and so not in the first 256 C# chars, but it *is* supported by the collation.

Answer (score 5):

This is because at ++255 the byte datatype silently overflows starting again at 0.
A byte can never represent a value that's not <= 255.

Try:

```
private static IEnumerable<char> AllSqlVarChars()
{
    List<char> chars = new List<char>(256);
    for (byte b = 0; b < 255; b++)
    {
    chars.Add((char)b);
    }
    return chars;
}
```